# Delete page with Word Interop Library using VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, word-interop

I am just building a VB .NET application which creates a Word document using the interop library.

The document looks like this:

[image]

I want to delete the blank page. I already tried two possibilities:

- I delete the last paragraph.
- I delete the particular page with code from the Internet.

Both did not work. Please provide some code in VB .NET if possible. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, otherwise we can not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid adding the last "Abschnittwechsel" (section break).